# Networkx Centrality measures in 'count' of inbound/outbound edges

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I am trying to get absolute number of inbound/outbound edges of a directed graph. Centrality gives me the fraction of nodes connectable from a selected node. i want to compare multiple sub-graphs, the fraction/ratio is not give me exact comparison.

I am currently multiplying `DiGraph.number_of_nodes()-1` with Centrality measures. but i am unsure this is the easiest way. Are there any existing Networkx builtin algorithm or functions?

```py
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,'Id_From','Id_To',edge_attr=True,create_using=nx.DiGraph)
size=G.number_of_nodes()
DegreeCentrality=nx.degree_centrality(G)
DegreeCentrality.update(x*size for x in DegreeCentrality.items())


Example expected result
Node1: InDegreeCentrality: 4 (number of incoming edges to node1)
Node1: OutDegreeCentrality: 3 (number of outgoing edges from node1)
Node1: DegreeCentrality: 7 (Total number of edges linked to node1)
..
..
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to get summarized in-degree and out-degree for all nodes. Networkx has built-in functions for it - in_degree and out_degree. You can use generators that iterate through nodes and these functions:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(20, 0.3, directed=True)
print('IN AVG:', np.mean([G.in_degree(n) for n in G.nodes]))
print('OUT AVG:', np.mean([G.out_degree(n) for n in G.nodes]))
print('ALL AVG:', np.mean([G.degree(n) for n in G.nodes]))
print('IN SUM:', np.sum([G.in_degree(n) for n in G.nodes]))
print('OUT SUM:', np.sum([G.out_degree(n) for n in G.nodes]))
print('ALL SUM:', np.sum([G.degree(n) for n in G.nodes]))
```

It will print:

```
IN AVG: 5.65
OUT AVG: 5.65
ALL AVG: 11.3
IN SUM: 113
OUT SUM: 113
ALL SUM: 226
```

Comment: No, I am not looking for 'mean'. i want to get `count` of incoming & outgoing edges at node level. the builtin centrality functions in networkx provides relative score (as a fraction of number of nodes in the graph).

Comment: @Kannanc This answer gives you the totals for the entire graph, but you can decompose it to get the degrees of each node. The `n` in each list comprehension is the node in the graph, so you can use `G.in_degree(1)` to get the in-degree of node 1 (number of incoming edges). Same for `G.out_degree(1)` (number of outgoing edges). The total degree is `G.degree(1)`, or the sum of in- and out-degree.

Comment: If you want to use degrees of particular nodes, just use `G.in_degree(n)`, `G.out_degree(n)` and `G.degree(n)`, as you can see in my code.

Answer (score 0):

After going through the Networkx tutorial, i can achieve what i wanted above using resources on this page: https://jfinkels-networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/classes/digraph.html

Specifically;

**DiGraph.in_degree**
https://jfinkels-networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.in_degree.html#networkx.DiGraph.in_degree

**DiGraph.out_degree**
https://jfinkels-networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.out_degree.html#networkx.DiGraph.out_degree

PS: "centrality" converts into ratios.